# Creating a pure UDF iso

Tags: 18.04, iso, udf

I need to create ISO files that use UDF and only UDF, no ISO9660 or Joliet. I was using genisoimage and Xfburn, but I discovered that the presence of a ISO9660 filesystem in the ISO files was causing problems during situations when users wanted to extract them rather than mount them.

Unfortunately the only answer I've been able to find on the subject requires you to specify the amount of space you need for the UDF filesystem ahead of time, instead of having it dynamically conform to the files I'm putting inside. That would take too long.

I would prefer using something that either uses command line or a GUI that doesn't require the installation of a ton of GNOME stuff since I'm on Xfce4, but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mkudffs` creates pure UDF files and filesystems with no ISO-9660 data structures
`mkudffs` is part of the [udftools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/udftools) package

```
sudo apt install udftools
```

See the manpage here : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mkudffs.8.html

You first need to generate a blank file to contain the image. That is, you must set de filesize before 'filling' it by file copy. You can set the filesize you want/need determining it with `du` against the source directory

Example: create a CD image file:

```
truncate -s 650M /dest/cdimage.udf
mkudffs --media-type=cdrw /dest/cdimage.udf
sudo mkdir /media/udfimage
sudo mount -t udf -o loop,rw /dest/cdimage.udf /media/udfimage
sudo cp -R /src/files /media/udfimage
# After the data has been copied to the image,
# unmount the image and detach the loopback device:
# sudo umount /dev/loop0
# sudo rmdir /media/udfimage
```

Comment: Are you able to just rename UDF to ISO?

Comment: sure, you set the file extension you want